# How to use encrypted store-uri in Spring ImapIdleChannelAdapter

Tags: spring, spring-integration, imap

Sample spring configuration is as below.

```
<int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter id="mailAdapter"
    store-uri="imaps://${"username"}:${"password"}@imap-server:993/INBOX"
    java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"
    channel="emails"
    should-delete-messages="false"
    should-mark-messages-as-read="true">
</int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter>
```

I wish to keep the password field encrypted in properties file and decrypt it in the code. I am not sure on how to set mailReceiver property of ImapIdleChannelAdapter to my custom version of ImapMailReceiver.
Please let me know if there is any way to do this.

All of my configurations are in XML as described above. 
Above solution of adding the  defifnation did not work may be I am doing something wrong.  Then I tried using XML + Java configuration, as below.

```
    @Configuration
public class EmailConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ImapIdleChannelAdapter customAdapter() {
        ImapIdleChannelAdapter adapter = new ImapIdleChannelAdapter(mailReceiver());
        adapter.setOutputChannel(outputChannel());
        adapter.setErrorChannel(errorChannel());
        adapter.setAutoStartup(true);
        adapter.setShouldReconnectAutomatically(true);
        adapter.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler());
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskImapMailReceiver mailReceiver() {
        TaskImapMailReceiver mailReceiver = new TaskImapMailReceiver("imaps://[username]:[password]@imap.googlemail.com:993/inbox");
        mailReceiver.setShouldDeleteMessages(false);
        mailReceiver.setShouldMarkMessagesAsRead(true);
        //mailReceiver.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties());
        mailReceiver.setMaxFetchSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        return mailReceiver;
    }
}
```

Also created empty errorChannel,outputChannel etc. I observed that Spring creates two instances one with xml config and other with java @Configuration. Where it was expected to use only java configuration. If I remove the xml config tag
 then it provides sigle imap instance with my mailReceiver but runs only once does not go periodic. also does not show IMAPS logs.

Just wondering if I need to do so much to encrypt the password. Is somthing wrong with my approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java configuration instead of XML...

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfigClass {

    @Bean
    public MyMailReceiver receiver() {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    public ImapIdleChannelAdapter adapter() {
        ImapIdleChannelAdapter adapter = new ImapIdleChannelAdapter(receiver());
        ...
        return adapter;
    }

}
```

If you are using XML for everything else, simply add this class as a `<bean/>` to your XML.

**EDIT**

Here's an example that works fine for me...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So42298254Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So42298254Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public TestMailServer.ImapServer imapServer() {
        return TestMailServer.imap(0);
    }

    @Bean
    public ImapMailReceiver receiver() {
        ImapMailReceiver imapMailReceiver = new ImapMailReceiver(imapUrl("user", "pw"));
        imapMailReceiver.setHeaderMapper(new DefaultMailHeaderMapper()); // converts the MimeMessage to a String
        imapMailReceiver.setUserFlag("testSIUserFlag"); // needed by the SI test server
        Properties javaMailProperties = new Properties();
        javaMailProperties.put("mail.debug", "true");
        imapMailReceiver.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties);
        return imapMailReceiver;
    }

    private String imapUrl(String user, String pw) {
        return "imap://"
                + user + ":" + pw
                + "@localhost:" + imapServer().getPort() + "/INBOX";
    }

    @Bean
    public ImapIdleChannelAdapter adapter() {
        ImapIdleChannelAdapter adapter = new ImapIdleChannelAdapter(receiver());
        adapter.setOutputChannelName("handleMail");
        return adapter;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "handleMail")
    public void handle(String mail, @Header(MailHeaders.FROM) Object from) {
        System.out.println(mail + " from:" + from);
        imapServer().resetServer(); // so we'll get the email again
    }

}
```

Comment: Above solution did not work. Let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Edited the question after implementing your solution, could you please suggest where am i going wrong.

Comment: Your config looks ok; you need to remove the adapter from the XML. I just wrote a quick boot app to test it against the test email server in spring-integration-test, and it works fine for me - see the edit to my answer

Comment: And I just tested against a GMail account and the idle functionality works just fine.

Comment: Thanks Garry, but it did not work for me probably due to some xml configurations are conflicting

Answer (score 0):

My intention was to use encrypted passwords in properties files.
So I changed my approach of getting into email receiving classes. I added inherited PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and implemented method convertPropertyValue() as below.

```
public class EncryptationAwarePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {
    private static final Logger logger  = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EncryptationAwarePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.class);

    @Override
    protected String convertPropertyValue(String originalValue) {
        if (originalValue.contains("{<ENC>}") && originalValue.contains("{</ENC>}")) {
            String encryptedTaggedValue = originalValue.substring(originalValue.indexOf("{<ENC>}"), originalValue.indexOf("{</ENC>}") + 8);
            String encryptedValue = originalValue.substring(originalValue.indexOf("{<ENC>}") + 7, originalValue.indexOf("{</ENC>}"));

            try {
                String decryptedValue = EncrypDecriptUtil.decrypt(encryptedValue);//EncrypDecriptUtil is my class for encription and decryption
                originalValue = originalValue.replace(encryptedTaggedValue, decryptedValue);
            } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
                logger.error("failed to decrypt property returning original value as in properties file.", e);
            }
        }
        return originalValue;
    }
}
```

And changed properties file to enclose encrypted value in custuom ENC tag
as

```
    mail.imap.task.url=imap://username:{<ENC>}encryptedPassword{</ENC>}@imap.googlemail.com:993/inbox
```